# Unity Mouse Input on Linux not working with the new Input system in the Editor

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, input, user-input

When I lock the mouse in my C# script and I try to access the Scroll value (in my case `scroll.y`) I always get 0.
When I hit `esc` and unlock the mouse the value shows correctly (-1 or 1) when I use the wheel. It also works, if I build the game.

I've created a InputData to manage my input:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class InputData : ScriptableObject
{

    public InputAction MovementAction;
    public InputAction LookAction;
    public InputAction ScrollAction;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        MovementAction.Enable();
        LookAction.Enable();
        ScrollAction.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        MovementAction.Disable();
        LookAction.Disable();
        ScrollAction.Disable();
    }
}
```

In this Script, i get the scroll delta:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class weaponSwitching : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int selectedWeapon = 0;

    public InputData actions;

    private float prevVal = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 scroll = actions.ScrollAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        Debug.Log(scroll.y);
        if (scroll.y > 0f)
        {
            selectedWeapon++;
            SelectWeapon();
        }
        else if (scroll.y < 0f)
        {

        }
    }
```

Thank you for any help! :)

Comment: Please show us your code - not all of it, just a small repro of the problem (i.e., a [mcve]).

Comment: I've added some code

Comment: [Oisin Carroll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10204254) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68669113) saying "Bit late, but I filed an issue on this a couple of days ago. Seems it's being worked on now at least. [https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linux-editor-ignores-mouse-scroll-wheel-input-when-the-cursor-is-locked-on-the-new-input-system](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/linux-editor-ignores-mouse-scroll-wheel-input-when-the-cursor-is-locked-on-the-new-input-system)"